# Mecha anime where a boy got jealous over a girl he likes for kissing an old man

Tags: story-identification, anime, character-identification, episode-identification, mind-control

I'm trying to find a somewhat old mecha anime that I used to watch at Hero TV channel. It's been driving me crazy over the past few years.

All I can remember in a specific episode, is that there was a shy type but cheerful boy who was really close to this pretty girl (either orange or kinda pinkish hair) whom he likes or even love, then at one point he tried to give her flowers. He headed to some sort of hideout where they keep the robots and there were scenes that they were getting them ready or some are just fixing them. He found her but was eventually kissing an older guy, I mean like about 50 years old, who was maybe an electrical engineer or scientist that works there. The boy got really jealous then headed to a forest where he cried and somehow has this angry expression but then a girl appeared. Which I presume he is friends with and asked him what he was doing there. The boy then stood up and approached the girl slowly and then grinned at her, the girl was kinda worried and the next thing that happened, it wasn't really shown since the scene showed the moon instead, but she was screaming because her clothes are being torn by the boy. Most likely the boy raped her. (It was some sort of flashback).

Then like years after, he was shown to have mind control powers or maybe it was something else. I once watched an episode where he was controlling a woman which I think was the mother of one of the characters, but she still looks young. I don't remember what he made her do, but a weird thing happened. He kissed the woman and maybe that's how he gets to control her.

I don't clearly remember what he looks like, but I think he was wearing a mask.

It was a really long time ago, but that specific episode was what's stuck with me.

Comment: What makes you call it a mecha anime? Nothing in the description even comes close to mentioning them. You can [edit] your post to provide extra details.

Comment: The title sounds like Episode 8 of *Gurren Lagann*, but the actual description sounds more like *Code Geass*, although I don't believe Lelouch ever raped anyone. Can you remember exactly when you watched this? That might help us narrow it down.

Comment: Considering it was broadcasted on Hero TV channel, it might be listed on [this list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_aired_by_Hero).